# Using Angular ng-show with ajax request to get details

Tags: angularjs, master-detail

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to put together a notification list. Pretty basic really. A summary list of notifications is displayed. The user can then click on a notification and the details of the notification are shown. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DexLab/wh38La8w/20/) shows what I've put together.

```js
var notificaitonsApp = angular.module('notificationsApp', []);
var notificationListCtrl = notificaitonsApp.controller('NotificationListCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.notifications = getNotifications();
            
            function getNotifications() {
                var Data = [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "primary_line": "Missing Timesheet Entry",
                    "secondary_line": "Jan 28th",
                    "summary_item": false,
                    "message": "A notification description. Do something here. Blah, blah, blah",         
                    "actions": [{
                        "type": "Navigation",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.cm/app/234",
                        "url_text": "Update"
                        },{
                        "type": "Post",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.com/app/api/v1/234",
                        "url_text": "Approve"
                        }]
                },{
                    "id": "2",
                    "primary_line": "Purchase Reqest Approval Needed",
                    "secondary_line": "Account 333445, Requested by James",
                    "summary_item": false,
                    "message": "A different notification message. Take action now.",
                    "actions": [{
                        "type": "Navigation",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.com/pr/requisitions/434",
                        "url_text": "Edit"
                    },{
                        "type": "Post",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.com/pr/api/v1/requisitions/434",
                        "url_text": "Approve"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "id": "3",
                    "primary_line": "Multiple Items Need Your Attention",
                    "secondary_line": "",
                    "summary_item": true,
                    "message": ""
                }, {
                    "id": "4",
                    "primary_line": "Your Time Off Request was Approved",
                    "secondary_line": "Jan 28th",
                    "summary_item": false,
                    "message": "Yet another notification message. You need to do something.",
                    "actions": [{
                        "type": "Navigation",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.com/pr/requisitions/434",
                        "url_text": "Edit"
                    }]
                }];
            
                return Data;
            }
            
            $scope.showNotificationDetail = function(notificationId) {
                $('div#' + notificationId).toggle(300);
            }
            
            $scope.doNotificationPost = function(postUrl) {
                console.log("POST: " + postUrl);
            }
            
            $scope.doNotificationNavigation = function(navigationUrl) {
                console.log("Navigation: " + navigationUrl);
            }
        }]);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #F8F6ED
}
ul
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 0;
}
li
{
    font-family: Georgia;
    background-color: #EFE7D5;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
a
{    
    text-decoration: none;
}
#primary
{
    padding: 1% 2% 0 2%;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #978778;
}
#secondary
{
    padding: 0 2% 1% 2%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5B4F48;
}

div.notification_hidden {
    display: none;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.submit {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right; auto;
    text-align: right;    
}

button.notification_button {
   width: 85px; 
   height: 30px;
}

button.action_button {
    background-color: #cf6b28;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding: 6px 15px;
}

button.modify-button {
    background-color: #978778;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px; 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="notificationsApp">
    <div ng-controller="NotificationListCtrl">
        <div>
            Notifications
        </div>
        <div id="notifications">
            <div ng-if="notifications.length == 0">
                No Notifications
            </div>
            <ul ng-if="notifications.length > 0" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
                <a ng-if="notification.summary_item == false" ng-href="#here" ng-click="showNotificationDetail(notification.id)">
                    <li id="primary">{{notification.primary_line}}</li>
                    <li id="secondary">{{notification.secondary_line}}</li>
                </a>
                <a ng-if="notification.summary_item == true" href="{{notification.summary_url}}" id="{{notification.id}}">
                    <li id="primary">{{notification.primary_line}}</li>
                </a>
                <div class="notification_hidden" id="{{notification.id}}">
                    <div class="inline-block">
                        <div class="inline" id="primary_line">
                            {{notification.primary_line}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline" style="float: right">
                            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAKCAYAAABi8KSDAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAAH1JREFUKFN1kEsKwCAMRL3/4Vzorq2fiJsW75A6UkVTFB46SYYkqlJuTslzPWpHzzfh/cExXi0gQTyEsz6/YoCANEDPsZEAMPSWuKV5KQYxOrZWV5Orcs0tAhA5NkYz0X/pRaBtHwOm7RhyGSCX3hZ2ZoPKmcY/7sD8pTz8AhpjX7xHPMGHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="Close"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="message_container">
                        {{notification.message}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit">
                        <div class="inline" ng-repeat="action in notification.actions">
                            <div class="inline" ng-if="action.type == 'Navigation'">
                                <button class="notification_button modify-button" ng-click="doNotificationNavigation(action.url)">{{action.url_text}}</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inline" ng-if="action.type == 'Post'">
                                <button class="notification_button action_button" ng-click="doNotificationPost(action.url)" type="submit">{{action.url_text}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

While this approach works I'd rather not load all the notifications with their details and actions just to display a summary list. I'd like to display the summary list and then when the user clicks on a notification, use an ajax request to get the notification details and then display the details.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I have a vague idea that I'll need a directive and a template but no idea how I would toggle the display of the notification details template. I'm hoping there is a simpler solution. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would simply do an AJAX request, initialize some $scope.detail variable from the success callback, and use ng-show or ng-if on a div showing the detail. Don't, ever, do DOM manipulation from a controller like you're doing.

Comment: Got it. No DOM manipulation. I did try what you suggested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DexLab/Lf67f7jc/2/). But you can only show detail for one notification at a time. Your comment and going over this old JSFiddle did give me an idea for a way to make this work though. I'll update if it works.

Comment: I am working on a solution aswell right now, give me a bit of time and I can hopefully post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assembled a Solution for your problem that uses alot of scope manipulation and working with scopes in general (I saw that you weren't quite famailiar with angular so I thought this might be helpfull for you to learn more about angular scopes).

First things first you can find my code in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iv4ixiFSq3FDf9PtILw1?p=preview) plnkr. And here:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.3" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-app="notificationsApp">
    <div ng-controller="NotificationListCtrl">
        <div>
            Notifications
        </div>
        <div id="notifications">
            <div ng-if="notifications.length == 0">
                No Notifications
            </div>
            <ul ng-if="notifications.length > 0" ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
                <a ng-if="notification.summary_item == false" ng-href="#here" ng-click="$parent.showdetail = !showdetail;loadData($parent);">
                    <li id="primary">{{notification.primary_line}}</li>
                    <li id="secondary">{{notification.secondary_line}}</li>
                </a>
                <a ng-if="notification.summary_item == true" href="{{notification.summary_url}}" id="{{notification.id}}">
                    <li id="primary">{{notification.primary_line}}</li>
                </a>
                <div id="{{notification.id}}" ng-show="showdetail">
                    <div class="inline-block">
                        <div class="inline" id="primary_line">
                            {{notification.primary_line}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline" style="float: right">
                            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAKCAYAAABi8KSDAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAAH1JREFUKFN1kEsKwCAMRL3/4Vzorq2fiJsW75A6UkVTFB46SYYkqlJuTslzPWpHzzfh/cExXi0gQTyEsz6/YoCANEDPsZEAMPSWuKV5KQYxOrZWV5Orcs0tAhA5NkYz0X/pRaBtHwOm7RhyGSCX3hZ2ZoPKmcY/7sD8pTz8AhpjX7xHPMGHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="Close"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="message_container">
                        {{notification.ressource.message}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit">
                        <div class="inline" ng-repeat="action in notification.ressource.actions">
                            <div class="inline" ng-if="action.type == 'Navigation'">
                                <button class="notification_button modify-button" ng-click="doNotificationNavigation(action.url)">{{action.url_text}}</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inline" ng-if="action.type == 'Post'">
                                <button class="notification_button action_button" ng-click="doNotificationPost(action.url)" type="submit">{{action.url_text}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

And my script:

```
var notificaitonsApp = angular.module('notificationsApp', []);
var notificationListCtrl = notificaitonsApp.controller('NotificationListCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http','$timeout',
        function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

            $scope.notifications = getNotifications();

            $scope.showdetail = false;

            function getNotifications() {
              var Data = [{
                "id": "1",
                "primary_line": "Missing Timesheet Entry",
                "secondary_line": "Jan 28th",
                "summary_item": false,
                "ressource":{
                    "message": "loading ..."
                }
                },{
                    "id": "2",
                    "primary_line": "Purchase Reqest Approval Needed",
                    "secondary_line": "Account 333445, Requested by James",
                    "summary_item": false,
                    "ressource":{
                        "message": "loading ..."
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "3",
                    "primary_line": "Multiple Items Need Your Attention",
                    "secondary_line": "",
                    "summary_item": true,
                    "message": ""
                }, {
                    "id": "4",
                    "primary_line": "Your Time Off Request was Approved",
                    "secondary_line": "Jan 28th",
                    "summary_item": false,
                    "ressource":{
                        "message": "loading ...",
                        "actions":[]
                    }
                }];

                return Data;
            }


            $scope.loadData = function(parent) {
             $timeout(function(){},1000).then(function(result){
               var value = {
                    "message": "A notification description. Do something here. Blah, blah, blah",         
                    "actions": [{
                        "type": "Navigation",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.cm/app/234",
                        "url_text": "Update"
                        },{
                        "type": "Post",
                        "url": "http://somedomain.com/app/api/v1/234",
                        "url_text": "Approve"
                        }]
                };
                parent.notification.ressource = value;
             });
            };


            $scope.doNotificationNavigation = function(navigationUrl) {
                console.log("Navigation: " + navigationUrl);
            }
        }]);
```

A short description of what I did:

I added a scope variable `showdetail` that I use to hide and show each notification. To understand how this works the way it works you have to know that every ng-if and ng-repeat creates a new isolated scope. This means that `$parent.showdetail = !showdetail;` alters the `showdetail` value of the parent scope and since this is used within a ng-if repeated in a ng-repeat we are actually altering the scope of the ng-repeat.

Now our ng-show is updated with this scope variable because the scope of our ng-show is also the scope of our ng-repeat in this example. Only a loading message should appear because only the static data is shown.

The `loadData($parent);` in our ng-click calls a function in our controller and delivers our parent scope object as a variable. In our controller we first wait for one scound to mimic an API call and then we alter the object given to us. This means that we alter the scope of our ng-repeat and inject the data obtained from our API into the scope. Angulars data binding will now make sure that our values are updated and shown without us explicitly watching or polling any variables.

Now the correct data should be shown without creating a directive or using any additional watches. I should note that this works just fine but if you want a more clear structure in your code you could use a Directive instead.

I hope this was helpfull to you and solves your problems, please let me know if anything is unclear.